# How to clean nodejs response after every user request?

Tags: node.js

Every time a user enter to our URL he get the response of the last user + his new response.
I'm new with nodejs and I think I don't understand the way this server works :)

Anyway, here you can see the app:
https://s1-nodejs.herokuapp.com **(You will need to reload the page to see the duplicate response every time you reload).**

And this is the code I deployed to Heroku:

```
const start = Date.now();
// using the http module
var http = require('http');
var https = require('https');
var request = require('request');

var domain;
var apiKey = 'example';
var domainResultJson = [];
var promises = [];


// look for PORT environment variable, 
// else look for CLI argument,
// else use hard coded value for port 8080
port = process.env.PORT || process.argv[2] || 8080;

// create a simple server
let server = http.createServer(function (req, res) {

    for (var i = 0 ; i < 10 ; i++  ) {
        var domain = 'example-'+i+'.com';

        promises.push(CheckIfDomainAvailable(https,domain,apiKey,domainResultJson));
    }

    Promise.all(promises).then(function(values) {
        //console.log(values);

        res.statusCode = 200;
        res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'text/plain');

        for (var i in values) {
            val = values[i];
            res.write(val);
        }
        res.end();
    }).catch(
        console.error
    );

    function CheckIfDomainAvailable(https,domain,apiKey,domainResultJson) {
        return new Promise(function (success, failure) {
            request('https://example.com/api/v1?'
                + 'apiKey=' + apiKey + '&d=' + domain + '', function (error, response, body) {
                if (!error && response.statusCode == 200) {
                    domainResultJson.push('1');
                    success(body);
                } else {
                    failure(error);
                }
            });
        });
    }

});

// listen on the port
server.listen(port, function () {

    console.log('app up on port: ' + port);

});
```

Comment: dont keep `promises` and  `domainResultJson` global

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to declare `let promises = [];` inside `function (req, res) { ... }`, like this:

```js
// ...
let server = http.createServer(function (req, res) {
    let promises = []; // <= Define promises container here.

    for (var i = 0 ; i < 10 ; i++  ) {
        var domain = 'example-'+i+'.com';

        promises.push(CheckIfDomainAvailable(https,domain,apiKey,domainResultJson));
    }
// ...
```